# Solr Replication not happening (only) of delete messages because of commit issue in solr 4.4.0

Tags: solr, replication, commit, dataimporthandler, requesthandler

I am facing a very weird behavior in Solr version 4.4.0

When I send following url request for indexing two documents, it works fine, ie, it writes the indexing message into respective core. Hence we can say that commit works fine.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/test2m-enduser/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true&optimize=false
```

Now when I give exact same url for delete of all documents, i see a different behavior. Although it reflects the result of delete query from solr console (ie, all documents get deleted). But indexing message does not commit to disc, i.e, I cannot see any new change in time stamp of any file in "data/index" folder.

Now if I send following url request, it writes this new index to "data/index" folder, i.e. commit actually happens

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/test2m-enduser/update?commit=true
```

So I am surprised that what is the difference between "dataimport...commit=true" and "update...commit=true". What is being called finally in both cases.

Because of above behavior delete messages are not getting replicated to slave.

I don't understand whether it is a problem of soft commit or hard commit. How should i proceed to tackle this problem. Any input or pointer will help.

Comment: What is the URL you use for deleting all documents?

Comment: same as i am using for indexing, i.e, http://localhost:8080/solr/test2m-enduser/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false&commit=true&optimize=false

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Solr version prior to 3.4, [commit is not called automagically if you're *only* deleting documents](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Special_Commands). From 3.4 and onwards commit is always called based on the value of `commit` in the url.

Comment: My solr version is: 4.4.0
So as per your comment, it should work, but it is not

Comment: I had an issue with the date format, my indexer was only accepting date formats with T and Z in it, when i inserted records with T and Z in the date format, the indexer was mis behaving from phoenix to solr sync